# Time warping / frequency modulation natural examples?

Tags: filters, audio, noise, modulation

"Time warping" defined as

$$
x(t) \rightarrow x(t - \tau(t))
$$
where $|\tau'(t)| < 1$ ($=1$ is time stopping, $=0$ is time shift, $>1$ is time reversal).

Where can this occur? A natural process, a measurement device artifact? I'm not interested in deliberately induced FM (e.g. encoding info in carrier). Preferably, the warp / modulation is global rather than frequency-selective. Image/3D/etc examples acceptable.

**My attempts**:

- audio recording played faster
- word spoken faster
- ambulance approaching at different speeds (Doppler effect)

Comment: Frequency and phase modulation?

Comment: @MBaz That's more of a multiplicative rather than additive time warping, but I'll count it; will look into examples. It's also important that we speak of a _global_ time warp rather than for selective frequencies.

Comment: Seems there's less examples than I imagined - I've loosened the criteria.

Comment: What do you mean by "global"?

Comment: @MBaz Acting upon all of $x$ rather than its frequential subset (sub-band), as in e.g. bandpassing. So if $x(t) = x_a(t) + x_b(t)$, then $x'(t) = x_a(t - \tau(t)) + x_b(t)$ won't do. (But I've lifted this criterion)

Comment: Like an audio flanger maybe?  Ultimately, it would be added with the original signal to get a given filter response though.  Maybe a Doppler shift?  This ones harder than I thought

Comment: @DanSzabo Yeah thought of these exact examples after asking - they're perfect, but maybe there's more

Answer (score 1):

That's a common technique in audio

1. Audio modulation effects like Flanger, Phaser and specifically Chorus
2. Pitch shifting, sample players, auto-tune, etc.
3. In a sense "sample rate conversion" would qualify
4. FM modulation synthesizers.